# Counting in javascript from math.pow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math, pow

I got this little piece of code which is used for a google maps.
To 'link' the markers to a filter there is a count.
Each marker has a props which holds a number so it will be able to filter.

at the minute the math.pow is used.
You understand the props for the markers go from 1-2-4-8-16-32 untill you get over millions and billions. What i'd like to do is alter the code so it does 1+1=2 1+2=3 4, 5 ,6 ,7 and so on so i don't have to fill in these HUGE numbers.

The code is here:

```
$.each(sizer,function(i,b){
    props+=($(b).is(':checked'))?Math.pow(2,i):0;
});
```

Comment: Asking people to "alter it to make it work" isn't going to get you very far. Why don't you try to alter it yourself, and if you run into some problems, post those problems and we can help you. Generally speaking, people are loathe to help those who will not help themselves.

Comment: I've tried it. as i stated. my java is not that good thats why i'm asking. Maybe you could have already answered my question in the time you spend typing your message.

Comment: Maybe you should post what you tried and you might have had your answer already rather than taking time trying to make it look like I'm at fault because you didn't like my comment or feel that I somehow owe you help. You're frustrated. That's fine. Taking your frustrations out on people who are already helping you get to your answer is not fine.

Comment: All i'm asking is how to change ~~ Math.pow(2,1) ~~to 1+i
in ~~~props+=($(b).is(':checked'))?Math.pow(2,i):0;~~~
And now you start being arogant and mean. If you want to help me then help me. if you dont want to help me then stop replying message that won't help me. gosh... stackoverflow is here so people can ask question and others can help. You're now helping at all so please leave this question if you don't want to help.

Comment: ($(b).is(':checked'))?i++:0;
this should work,as per Your Need I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is this:

```
$.each(sizer,function(i,b){
    props+=($(b).is(':checked')) ? i : 0;
});
```

There are two things for you to understand:

- the syntax of the ternary operator is as follows: `condition ? expr1 : expr2`. Basicly it is a one-line if/else statement - if the condition is true - execute the first expression, otherwise execute the second expression. You can read more about it on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- Math.pow is a built-in javascript function that accepts two numbers - a number and a power of this number. So Math.pow(2, i) means 2 to the power of i. This is something you probably guessed by now.

It is very hard to help more than that, because I don't have the rest of the code at my disposal. For example, how can I know what are the values of `sizer`? Etc...

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this tomorrow.
Funny how a 132 reputation person helps me and a 1567 reputation person starts arguing! Thanks again !
I'll put yours as answer as soon as i tried it, and it worked :)

Comment: The values are 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 and so on.
math.pow does 1^1 1^2 1^2 1^3 where 1 2 3 is the I.
i'm going to test your method now.

Comment: The answer to my question is yours. But it does create a problem which i now understand and cant fix. I'll have to use the math.pow way. Thanks for reacting!